# ParametricRegion example from documentation not running

Tags: regions, documentation

I tried running a piece of code in the examples listed in ***Scope*** in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html and it gives an error.

I tried running the below code to get a conical surface:

```
DiscretizeRegion[
ParametricRegion[
{h Cos[\[Theta]], h Sin[\[Theta]],h},
{{\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {h, 0, 3}}
]]
```

and I get the below error:

```
DiscretizeRegion::drf: "DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ParametricRegion[<<2>>]
```

I am running Mathematica 10.4.1.0 on Windows (64-bit)

Could you please help me diagnose the issue here?

Comment: It is working for me [See this](http://imgur.com/a/6gmZq)

Comment: It looks like this didn't work in 10.4.1, but it works in 11.1. You're using 11.1 documentation (most recent) if you're looking online. This example was NOT documented in 10.4.1, so it can't necessarily be expected to work there. I'm not sure where the update was, but you should upgrade your version of Mathematica.

Comment: It did not work for me in 11.0.1.

Comment: Thanks @user6014. It works for me on 11.1. I had put off upgrade, but this version really does much more

Comment: @Shivanand glad to hear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user6014 and @LouisB pointed out, Mathematica 11.1 is able to run it (I have a student license), but Mathematica 11.0 cannot (I have that installed on my lab computer). The documentation indeed seems to have been made for version 11.1 of Mathematica.